# Django ManyToMany CheckConstraint IntegerField

Tags: django, constraints, many-to-many

I have some models, 1 abstract, and 2 that inherit from the abstract model with a ManyToMany relationship. One model gets its members from the other model. I want to implement a constraint on this model so that its members can't be more than the Sum of the remaining_members on the original groups. I created a Q expression that expresses what I want to achieve, but I know it's not the right way to do it. How can I create the constraint with models that are related by a ManyToMany field?

```
class AbstractGroup(models.Model):
    members = models.IntegerField()
    
    class Meta:
        abstract=True

class OriginalGroup(AbstractGroup):
    remaining_members = models.IntegerField()
    new_group_members = ManyToManyField(NewGroup, related_name=new_group, related_query_name=new_group)


class NewGroup(AbstractGroup):
    name = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint( Q(members__lte=original_groups__sum__remaining_members, name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_available_members' ) )
        ]
```

Comment: You can't. `CHECK` constraints can only operate on the single record, hence you can not look to other rows (in the same table) or to different tables. Some/most databases do not even allow this.

Comment: Thanks, I won't use a constraint.